# "both at" vs. "at both"

Tags: prepositions

How should I use the word both in the following sentence?

> I have also been involved with ABET accreditation in the Department of
>   Mechanical Engineering at both / both at XX University and YY State University.

Comment: A comma might be included before 'both at', but they're both acceptable. 'At both' is probably higher-register.

Comment: This is subtle, but I would use "at both" if the program was somehow connected with or distributed between both locations, and I would use "both at" if the two identical programs were distinct from one another.

Comment: If I put "at" after "both" then I'd put another "at" after "and" to keep the two phrases grammatically parallel.

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful comments. There were two distinct programs: I have a feeling that "Both at" reads more smoothly than "at both". Although according to the first answer below, it may "imply a pairing before the phrase's occurrence".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**both** refers to two things or people together, and should be used next to words they refer to.  **both at/at both** breaks this rule, but since there is only one pair in your sentence, people can still get the idea.

**both at** implies a pairing before the phrase's occurrence, and **at both** implies a pair afterwards.  For example:

> I have also been involved with **ABET accreditation and grant writing** in the Department of Mechanical Engineering, **both at** XX University and YY State University.

If you use **at both**, you are referring to the universities:

> I have also been involved with ABET accreditation in the Department of Mechanical Engineering **at both XX University and YY State University**.

Since your pairing is at the end of the sentence, it would be best to use **at both**.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I am trying to express that I have been involved in two separate programs (although both Mechanical Engineering), at different universities.                                                                                          "I have also been involved with ABET accreditation of mechanical engineering programs both at/at both XX University and YY University. "